# Why doesn't modifying the .emacs file change the behavior of GNU Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm running GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows 7.  As mentioned in [this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html), I can type

```
C-x d ~/ RET
```

to determine the location of my home directory. In my case, Emacs returns:

```
e:/EmacsDocs
```

which, according to Windows Explorer, indeed contains a file `.emacs`.  When I open `.emacs` with Emacs, the file appears to be empty.

Now, I want to set Emacs so that it is in **overwrite mode** by default.  According to [this page](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oreily/unix/upt/ch32_05.htm), that can be done by adding the following to `.emacs`:

```
(setq-default overwrite-mode t)
```

But when I make this change to `.emacs` and close and reopen Emacs, Emacs does not overwrite when I select text and start typing.  (Rather, it still operates in *insertion mode*, with new characters inserted before the cursor.)

I also tried, for example, adding this command to `.emacs`, which according to [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html) will disable cursor blinking:

```
(blink-cursor-mode 0)
```

but again, there is no change when I restart Emacs.

How can I tell if Emacs is actually reading the `.emacs` in the home directory (upon restarting Emacs)?

Comment: See if your recently started emacs have a `messages` buffer that may contain some clue (to switch to `messages` buffer, the default command is `C-x b messages RET`). It's also useful to start emacs using the `--debug-init` parameter from the command line (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Debugging-a-customization-file.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing what Emacs calls `overwrite-mode` with the requested behavior "*overwrite when I select text and start typing*".

In Emacs, the latter behavior is called `delete-selection-mode`, and `overwrite-mode` means that when you type text (without selecting anything), any existing text that follows the cursor is overwritten by what you type.

Most Emacs users do not turn on `overwrite-mode` by default, and they just hit the `insert` key (typically to the left of the `home` key) to toggle `overwrite-mode on/off when they need/want to.

One way to turn on `delete-selection-mode` by default is to put *one* of the following in your init file (`.emacs`):

```
(setq delete-selection-mode t)
```

or

```
(delete-selection-mode)
```

Another way is to customize the option `delete-selection-mode` using `M-x customize-option RET delete-selection-mode RET` and save the customized value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the file outside of Emacs, just type

```
C-x C-f ~/.emacs
```

and add your configurations there. Save with

```
C-x C-s
```

and restart. This should work, since ~ in Emacs defaults to the home directory.